# Repeating same data in sql on autosave

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, autosave

i am trying to auto save some data after a certain time in a database.here is my view code

```
<div id="main">
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
  <h1>Purchase Product Detail</h1>


  <?php
  echo form_open( 'shop/buy_product/submit' );
  ?>
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Shop Name
      </td>
      <td>

<?php
echo form_dropdown( 'shop', $tags );


//echo form_dropdown('shop', $options, 'Yellow');
?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        SL.
      </th>
      <th>
        Product code
      </th>
      <th>
        Product Name
      </th>

      <th>
        Rate
      </th>
      <th>
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th>
        Total
      </th>
      <th>
        Sell Price
      </th>

    </tr>
<?php for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ): ?>
      <tr>
        <td width="10">
  <?php echo $i; ?>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input size="10" type="text" name="code[]" value="<?php echo ''; ?>" id="code_<?php echo $i; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
      <name="product[]" value="<?php echo ''; ?>" id="product_<?php echo $i; ?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input size="10"type="text" name="rate[]" value="<?php echo ''; ?>" id="rate_<?php echo $i; ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input size="10" type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo ''; ?>" id="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" />
      </td>
      <td width="15%">
      <name="total[]" value="<?php echo ''; ?>" id="total_<?php echo $i; ?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input size="10" type="text" name="sell[]" value="<?php echo ''; ?>" id="sell" />
      </td>

      </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>







  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>



</div>
```

and here is my model

```
    function add_product()

        {
            $data  = array();
                $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
                for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['code']); $i++){
                    if($_POST['code'][$i] != '')
                    {
                        $data[] = array(
                            'code' => $_POST['code'][$i],
                            'shop' => $_POST['shop'],
                            'memo' => $_POST['memo'],
                            'rate' => $_POST['rate'][$i],
                            'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'][$i],
                            'total' =>( $_POST['rate'][$i]*$_POST['quantity'][$i]),
                            'date' => $todayDate
                            );
                    }
                }
                $linksCount = count($data);

                if($linksCount){
                    $this->db->insert_batch('purchase', $data);
                }

                return $linksCount;

        }
```

my main problem is when the auto save function executed it insert all the data in the database. its repeating the same data again and again after a certain.can anyone help me fixing this.

Comment: where is the auto save function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using JS/jQuery for the autosave function. Add a hidden field to your form, say `insert_id`. Before doing any inserts, check if that field has a value. If so: update the db row corresponding to the insert_id, otherwise, insert_id is empty so you'll need to insert. Upon insert, load the hidden field with the current insert_id using jQuery.